# Django framework: Saving a ManyToMany Field in a form using save_m2m() method throws error

Tags: python, django, many-to-many

I'm trying to build a cookbook web-app with django. The recipies you can create can be in several cookbooks you can create. That's why 'cookbooks' is a ManyToMany field in recipies. 
By creating a recipe it shows multiple checkboxes where you can check several cookbooks.
Saving this throws an error saying:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'a'
```

in my `views.py`:

```
def create_recipe(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        return render(request, 'cookbook/login.html')
    else:
        form = RecipeForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            recipe = form.save(commit=False)
            recipe.user = request.user
            recipe.picture = request.FILES['picture']
            file_type = recipe.picture.url.split('.')[-1]
            file_type = file_type.lower()
            if file_type not in IMAGE_FILE_TYPES:
                context = {
                    'recipe': recipe,
                    'form': form,
                    'error_message': 'Image file must be PNG, JPG, or JPEG',
                }
                return render(request, 'cookbook/create_recipe.html', context)
            recipe.save()
            form.save_m2m()
            cookbook = Cookbook.objects.filter(user=request.user)
            return render(request, 'cookbook/index.html', {'cookbook': cookbook})
        context = {
            "form": form,
        }
        return render(request, 'cookbook/create_recipe.html', context)
```

in my `forms.py`:

```
class RecipeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    directions = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
    ingredients = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)

    class Meta:
        model = Recipe
        fields = ['title', 'ingredients', 'directions', 'picture', 'cookbooks']

    def __init__ (self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RecipeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields["cookbooks"].widget = forms.widgets.CheckboxSelectMultiple()
        self.fields["cookbooks"].help_text = ""
        self.fields["cookbooks"].queryset = Cookbook.objects.all()
```

Comment: If you're getting an error, you should post the exact message and the full traceback.

Comment: could you post the models??